# How bad it is using the same IV twice with AES/GCM?

Tags: aes, initialization-vector, gcm, nonce

I understand that initialization vectors (IV) should not be used twice when using AES/GCM. I am using a counter as an initialization vector. Every time I send out a new packet (I am developing an UDP based protocol that needs packet encryption) I increment the counter and use it as IV.

However, since I will generally need that protocol to transfer files and to send [keepalives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive) for very very extended periods of time, in principle for very large files it is conceivable to send more than $2^{32}$ packets, or over the years it is conceivable to send out $2^{32}$ keepalives. To keep the IVs always unique, I would probably need to use a 64 bits integer, but that is 4 bytes more of overhead per packet, that can sum up to quite large quantities which I would like to avoid if not strictly necessary.

So I wonder: how bad it is to reuse the IVs with AES/GCM? Can I have an idea of how dangerous that can be? I mean: if as soon as I repeat an IV **once** I get immediately so easily exposed to an attack that I could just give out my key publicly, then I have to take countermeasures. However, if that becomes dangerous only when I use the same IV a lot of times, that is completely another thing.

Comment: As per its definition IV can not be reused. Re-using IV - it would no longer be an IV anymore. That is because IV is required to be random.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Even a *single* AES-GCM nonce reuse can be catastrophic.**

- A *single* nonce reuse leaks the xor of plaintexts, so if one plaintext is known the adversary can completely decrypt the other.  This is the same as for a two-time pad.
- In messages up to $\ell$ blocks long, after a *single* nonce reuse the adversary can narrow the authentication key down to $\ell$ possibilities with polynomial root-finding and thereby forge messages with high success probability $1/\ell$.

  - How?  An $\ell$-block message is a polynomial of degree $\ell$ with zero constant term; the authenticator under secret key $r, s$ is $m \mapsto m(r) + s$, where $r$ is reused between messages and $s$ is derived as a secret function of the nonce.  Find authenticators $a = m(r) + s$ and $a' = m'(r) + s$ for distinct messages under the same nonce, and only the ${\leq}\ell$ possible roots of the degree-$\ell$ polynomial $m(r) - m'(r) + a' - a$ in $r$ are possible values of the authentication key.

**Use 96-bit nonces; if you don't—if, instead, you use smaller *or* larger nonces—it will be *as if* you chose nonces randomly, and the number of messages you can safely handle drops dramatically.**  But you can, of course, pad, say, a 64-bit nonce into 96 bits: what matters is only that the nonces be *unique*.

If the cost of a >32-bit nonce is prohibitive, you could periodically rekey.  For example, if you first establish a long-term key $k$, you can use $\operatorname{HMAC-SHA256}_k(i)$ as the key during the $i^{\mathit{th}}$ epoch, where each epoch covers four billion messages, and $i$ is encoded into a bit string in some canonical way.

Answer (score 13):

Reusing an IV **once** opens you up to someone finding the XOR of those two plaintext, seriously compromising their confidentiality. Moreover, with GCM, a single IV reuse leaks significant information about the key used for authentication; if there are even a few pairs of reused IVs (not even one IV used many times; a few IVs each of which are used twice is enough) can compromise the authentication key. GCM being a stream cipher, it is totally malleable if the authentication mechanism fails (the MAC is the *only* thing preventing tampering).

Moreover, there are mild concerns if you use a non-96-bit IV with NIST-spec GCM. NIST's GCM is designed for 96-bit IVs, and if you specify a different-length one there are weaknesses in the function used to compute the "real" IV.

[Source.](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/documents/Joux_comments.pdf)

Comment: I'd just like to add that if you ARE concerned about the possibility of IV reuse, possibly due to being on a platform with really poor randomness, then you can use an IV misuse resistant scheme.

Comment: @cpast Thanks! I will definitely try to avoid reusing then. About the problem of the iv not being 96 bits long: can I just pad it with zeros, I suppose?

Comment: @YehudaLindell I am just using IVs sequentially, so random collision shouldn't be my concern, I think.

Comment: Actually, if you just reuse an IV once (for distinct plaintexts/AADs), the attacker can limit the possible values for $H$ to a handful of values.