# AES Padding (Nullbytes vs PKCS7)

Tags: aes, cbc, padding, ecb

I currently implement the AES(128,192,256)(ECB,CBC). Does the type of padding affect security?
I just want to fill the blocks with null bytes.

Answer (score 5):

**Padding**

You cannot fill the remaining blocks with the null bytes unless

- The message has a fixed size that doesn't require sending file sizes.
- The file size is sent over the channel.
- The message doesn't contain null-bytes.

In the general, the padding must be unambiguous. `10..0` padding can be fine.

- if data is `1234567890000000`

  now the data is `123456789` or `1234567890` or `12345678900` or..
- if you use `10..0` then with the data `1234567890001000`

  it will be clear that the data is `123456789000`

You can use PKCS#7 padding for ECB and CBC mode. PKCS#7 supports modes have block sizes larger than 64-bit block up to 255. The previous one, PKCS#5 padding had support up to 64-bit block size that was fine for DES.

In PKCS#7 padding, the remaining bytes count is padded as a byte value. For example;

```
123456789ABCDEF1     here consider the integers as bytes like 1 = 0x01
123456789ABCDE22
123456789ABCD333
```

Then the removal of padding bytes result in

```
123456789ABCDEF
123456789ABCDE
123456789ABCD
```

If the last block is full an additional block is filled with `1F`

```
0123456789ABCDEF next block is full of `1F`s
```

- The known padding methods are not limited to the above methods see more in [Wikipedia: Padding_(cryptography)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)).
- For the complete difference between PKCS#5 and PKCS#7 see this canonical question [What is the difference between PKCS#5 padding and PKCS#7 padding](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9043/18298)

**CBC padding Oracle attack**

For CBC mode operation, if padding oracle is applicable then the server can act like a decryption oracle. This attack academically first published  [in 2002 by Serge Vaudenay](https://www.iacr.org/cryptodb/archive/2002/EUROCRYPT/2850/2850.pdf). Although the servers are patched there are attacks based on the downgrade like [Lucky13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_Thirteen_attack) and [Poodle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POODLE). Keep your servers on the secure level! TLS 1.3 has huge clean ups and it has no more CBC mode of operation. The TLS 1.3 encryption modes with their IDs;

- {0x13,0x01} - TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
- {0x13,0x02} - TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
- {0x13,0x03} - TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
- {0x13,0x04} - TLS_AES_128_CCM_8_SHA256
- {0x13,0x05} - TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256

One can see how the padding oracle attacks work in these [answers](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76713/18298) and remember if applicable the attacker can decrypt all of the message not only the padded part.

- If there is no such padding oracle attack then it is secure. Example the data stored as data-at-rest.

**Padless modes**

It is better to use a mode like [CTR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_(CTR)) and [OFB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Output_feedback_(OFB)) modes that don't require padding at all. They can work with arbitrary byte sizes.

**Forget ECB**

Don't use ECB which is insecure leaks patterns, it is not a [probabilistic encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_encryption), not even secure against KPA attacks on multi-block messages. Some even don't call it as a mode of operation.

**Modern Modes**

The all above modes are also called archaic mode of operation and they can have at most CPA. In modern Cryptography, we use and suggest to use [Authenticated Encryption (AE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) (AEAD: AE with associated data) modes like AES-GCM and ChaCha20-Poly1305 which can have IND-CCA2. These will provide you Confidentiality, Integrity, and Authentication, all in one. And remember, never use a key-IV pair again in these modes. If you want only leak about the same message is sent nothing more then use a [misuse-resistant](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/82105/18298) mode like SIV. AES-GCM-SIV will be the future.

**There is a new mode**

[Daence: Salsa20 and ChaCha in Deterministic Authenticated Encryption with no noNCEnse](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/067.pdf) as of 2020 by Taylor R Campbell

> We present Daence, a deterministic authenticated cipher based on a pseudorandom function family and a universal hash family, similar to SIV. We recommend instances with Salsa20 or ChaCha, and Poly1305, for high performance, high security, and easy deployment.

This mode uses the Associated Data (AD) to eliminate the case that even the same message is sent under the same key-IV pair if the AD is different than the ciphertext messages will be different up to some probability.

Comment: Ok thanks, That answers my question

Comment: A null-padding works if the plain text is known to contain no null bytes (like plain text).

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann thanks. updated.

Comment: I don't send the cipher^^. I want to encrypt programs on a cnc machine.XD. I implemented the last 3 days the AES(128,192,256)-Algorithm for this. Nullbytes are not written if I decrypt the cipher. So they don't care. 
I was just wondering if you were endangering security.

Comment: No, if they do, then we have a huge problem for the AES that or DES.

Comment: Is the CBC-mode sufficiently safe for my project?

Comment: As long as your key is secure, there is no problem. How do you store key? Where do you store the information? What is the life cycle of the storage, etc.

Comment: I want to store the key in my head^^. The programs are stored on the hard disk.

Comment: Then the AES key will be weak. You need a PBKDF2 to produce a key from your password. There are tons of questions about this. Either use a password manager to store the key for you, or use a high entropy password like diceware and PBKDF2/HKDF..

Comment: Ok, then I will use my Passwordmanager (Keepass) for create a password and store them.

Comment: You can upvote and accept to close the post. For others, this indicates that the answer solved the problem. This is SO way. :)